# Linking to a Specific JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript

Ok, I'll try to explain this as best I can. Website A has an archive page that uses some JS to  filter a search. Basically, you click a person's link and it will bring up every document that person is included in. It does not change the URL, however. It filters out every document that does not include that specific person.

On Website B, I want to be able to go directly to a specific filtered list without having to clink the link on Website A.

Example: On Website A when I click the link for "Bob Peterson", it brings up a list of documents that JS has assigned Bob Peterson to. On Website B, I want to put a "Bob Peterson" link that will go directly to Website A's "Bob Peterson" list. I don't want the user from Website B to have to click on the "Bob Peterson" link on Website A.

Is there a certain type of anchor tag that can achieve this?

Comment: Can you edit both websites? Are they hosted on the same domain?

Comment: Website A can include code to perform the filter automatically, e.g., based on the URL hash at page-load time. Site B cannot compel site A to run a script; that would be a tremendous security violation (assuming A and B signify different domains).

Comment: You can implement a server side REST api to query the server for Website A's data values and return a JSON structure containing said values to Website B

Comment: Create `Shared Function` on site A that takes `parameter` as filter list. Call that function from site B through ajax(`type post`) on click of anchor and  get the data back.

Comment: Yes, TheConstructor. Both pages will be hosted on the same site.